# Удалить пустые значения

Tags: yii, yii2

Есть модель которая формирует массив данных, как удалить пустые значения в этом массиве, если там ничего нет?

```
class Account extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public function rules()
    {

        return [
            [['Name', 'register_Time'], 'required']
        ];
    }

}
```

Comment: ......`unset()`

Comment: unset() а как использовать?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unset.php#refsect1-function.unset-examples

Comment: Вы не могли бы объяснить по какой причине вы привели кусок с правилами валидации?

Comment: Удалить пустоту в массиве - array_filter($array)

Comment: Bookin - я думаю вы хотели спросить - почему вы считаете что это массив?  - А что это? Только массивы заключаются в крадратные скобки.